# GRUB has dissapeared

Tags: grub2

So the awesome Windows 10 gave me the blue screen error and after that and restoring GRUB doesn't appear anymore (I had dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu14).

How can i get it back?

Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Steps :**

**Step 1:**
First live boot into Ubuntu using flashed (Bootable) penderive or DVD.

**Step 2:**
Open the terminal, you can do that by pressing **"Ctrl+Alt+T"**.

**Step 3:**
Run the below command to check the bootable partition,

#Displaying the partitions and find the bootable partition might say 'ubuntu' or somthing alike like 'Linux' :

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

[My partition list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAtxh.png)
- In the above image you will see two partitions with the name 'Linux' [sda6 and sda7] but you will see only one & name can be different in your case and that would be your targeted partition in the below command and for the your shake buddy if you really interested in Linux then stop dual booting just install it as your primary OS and believe me you will fall in love just like everybody else has fallen.

**Final steps:** (Means run the below commands as well)
Mounting the bootable partition in this case mine is **sda6** :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
```

#Bind the dir to install the configs :

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo moutn --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

# Giving root permission :

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

# Installing partition configs (Grub) :

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Here after running the last command it should say like **"Grub installed successfully"** then just reboot the system and unplug the bootable device.

You should get your grub back now.

If above method doesn't work for you then send me the screenshot of the error you might got in the process and the screenshot of the terminal result you get when you run "sudo fdisk -l" .

Comment: Hello, I followed your steps successfully but still Grub doesn't appear when booting my PC...